# Consider autocorrelation in a Linear Quantile mixed models (LQMM)

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-models, quantile

(I am using R and the lqmm package)

I was wondering how to consider autocorrelation in a Linear Quantile mixed models (LQMM).

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df1<-data.frame(    Time=seq(as.POSIXct("2017-11-13 00:00:00",tz="UTC"),
                as.POSIXct("2017-11-13 00:1:59",tz="UTC"),"sec"),
            HeartRate=rnorm(120, mean=60, sd=10),
            Treatment=rep("TreatmentA",120),
            AnimalID=rep("ID01",120),
            Experiment=rep("Exp01",120))

df2<-data.frame(    Time=seq(as.POSIXct("2017-08-11 00:00:00",tz="UTC"),
                as.POSIXct("2017-08-11 00:1:59",tz="UTC"),"sec"),
            HeartRate=rnorm(120, mean=62, sd=14),
            Treatment=rep("TreatmentB",120),
            AnimalID=rep("ID02",120),
            Experiment=rep("Exp02",120))

df<-rbind(df1,df2)

head(df)
```

With: 
The heart rates (HeartRate) that are measured every second on some animals (AnimalID). These measures are carried during an experiment (Experiment) with different treatment possible (Treatment). Each animal (AnimalID) was observed for multiple experiments with different treatments. I wish to look at the effect of the variable Treatment on the 90th percentile of the Heart Rates but including Experiment as a random effect and consider the autocorrelation (as heart rates are taken every second). (If there is a way to include AnimalID as random effect as well it would be even better)

Model for now:

```
library(lqmm)
model<-lqmm(fixed= HeartRate ~ Treatment, random= ~1| Exp01, data=df, tau=0.9)
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

For resources on thinking about this type of problem you might look at chapters 17 and 19 of Koenker et al. 2018 *Handbook of Quantile Regression* from CRC Press. Neither chapter has nice R code to go from, but they discuss different approaches to the kind of data you're working with. lqmm does use nlme machinery, so there may be a way to customize the covariance matrices for the random effects, but I suspect it would be easiest to either ask for help from the package author or to do a deep dive into the package code to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Another resource is the quantile regression model for mixed effects models accounting for autocorrelation in 'Quantile regression for mixed models with an application to examine blood pressure trends in China' by Smith et al. (2015). They model a bivariate response with a copula, but you could do the simplified version with univariate response. I think their model only at this points incorporates lag-1 correlation structure within subjects/clusters. The code for that model does not seem to be available online either though.